# Found a weird user giving out SE account details

Tags: bug, spamming, user-accounts

I have posted [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277695/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-the-fixed-resistor-in-a-light-dependent-voltage-di) and found myself surprised about a comment. (Check last comment to the posted question, the comment by the user who is called "asdf"). "asdf" is most probably a bot, and is giving out SE account details. If you check the comment, "asdf" posted a link as well. I don't know where the link goes to, and I don't want to find out(probably spam/virus). I flagged the user. Is this the first time users like this have appeared on EE stackexchange? I have never seen bot users before. Anyways, I flagged it as the "other" category and explained. It is obvious that it is a spam account, so I think it should be deleted. Any mods reading, can you please delete the account. And does anyone have any proposed solutions on how to block spam accounts?

Comment: Just checked and the user's comment was removed.

Comment: Hmm... The users profile has legitimate questions in it... Now I am plain confused. I have checked and the account has been suspended for a week. Weird, an account with legit EE questions, but makes spam comments. Maybe the questions are there to make the user seem like a regular user. Or maybe I'm completely wrong. Either way, that user has given out SE account details.

Comment: the user in question has already been suspended for 7 days; also, while they *claimed* to give out SE account details, we don't have any evidence as to the veracity of their claims.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the comment is still spam.

Comment: it indeed is, and it's good you posted here and flagged it.  (I flagged one of his comments on sight as well, btw.)

Comment: Asdf was a legitimate and active user. I think I answered an Asdf question once. It's quite likely the account got hacked. Since last activity (legitimate) across sites is 2015, a ban is in order. Hopefully the human behind the account returns some time soon.

Comment: @Asmyldof -- hopefully the original human behind the account can regain control of it and isn't locked out forevermore!

Comment: This makes me wonder:if his account really got hacked,that means the same thing can happen to any other user...or not.Maybe he just had a very weak password,only SE staff can know this.Maybe it was a friend/relative who is abusing his account.I just hope and trust SE will keep everything in check.

Comment: So if he was a legitimate user, then yes, it seems as if his account got hacked. Maybe it's a good idea to contact SE about the possible issue?

Comment: The moderators are already dealing with the issue.If they will need to ,they will contact SE.I only hope that the site doesn't have some vulnerabilty who can compromise users.But I don't want spread rumors,I don't know exactly what happened.Again,the mods will take care of it.